# In Ubuntu, how do I authenticate to trigger a Jenkins job remotely using the CLI?

Tags: jenkins, authentication

As far as I understand, using the Linux CLI, builds can be triggered remotely using the curl command and the following URL syntax:

<JENKINS_URL>/job/<JOB_NAME>/build?token=<TOKEN_NAME>

Example:

```
$ curl http://localhost:8080/job/MyJob/build?token=my-token
```

However, when I run the command, I receive the following:

```
Authentication required
<!--
-->
</body></html>
```

Is authentication done using the CLI or the Jenkins web interface? How do I authenticate?

Answer (score 1):

This is covered [in the documentation](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/system-administration/authenticating-scripted-clients/).  In short, if you are triggering via HTTP, you need to generate an authentication token and use it with HTTP Basic auth, for instance:

```
curl -X POST -L --user your-user-name:apiToken https://jenkins.example.com/job/your_job/build
```